# Dovecot quota-warning executable can not log to stdout

Tags: logging, dovecot, stdout

I'm running dovecot with DB based userdb and passdb inside a docker container using the [s6-overlay](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay).

Everything runs very well. Now I tried to add [quota warnings](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Quota/Configuration#Quota_warnings) and run into a problem with logging to `/dev/stdout`.

#### Error message

Whenever the warning mail should be sent I see this message getting logged:

```
Oct 28 10:27:01 quota-warning: Error: Can't open log file /dev/stdout: No such device or address
Oct 28 10:27:01 quota-warning: Fatal: master: service(quota-warning): child 460 returned error 75
```

#### Relevant dovecot config

I've set log path to `/dev/stdout` to let S6 capture the logs for me. And I added a quota warning script following the manual. Here's the relevant config:

```
log_path = /dev/stdout
first_valid_uid = 100
mail_uid = vmail
mail_gid = dovecot
mail_privileged_group = dovecot
mail_home = /var/mail/domains/%d/%n
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/domains/%d/%n**
plugin {
  quota = maildir:User quota
  quota_exceeded_message = Storage quota for user %u exceeded
  quota_rule2 = Trash:storage=+100M
  quota_grace = 10%%
  quota_status_success = DUNNO
  quota_status_nouser = DUNNO
  quota_status_overquota = "552 5.2.2 Mailbox is full"
  quota_warning = storage=85%% quota-warning 85 %u %d
}
service quota-warning {
  executable = script /usr/local/bin/quota-warning.sh
  user = vmail
  group = dovecot
  unix_listener quota-warning {
    user = dovecot
    mode = 0666
  }
}
```

#### Quota warning script

```
#!/bin/sh
PERCENT=$1
USER=$2
DOMAIN=$3
cat << EOF | /usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d $USER -o "plugin/quota=maildir:User quota:noenforcing"
From: no-reply@$DOMAIN
Subject: Qutoa warning

Your mailbox quota is at $PERCENT%.
EOF
```

#### S6 dovecot service

The S6 `run` script to start dovecot is very simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/sbin/dovecot -F -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
```

Log output from `/dev/stdout` is captured via a `logs/run` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec logutil-service /logs/dovecot
```

#### What I've tried

Everything works as soon as I change `log_path` to a static file like `/tmp/dovecot.log`. But that's not what I want.

So as I see it there's no `/dev/stdout` created for the quota-warning script and I have no idea how to fix this.

For the record: Everything else from dovecot is logged just fine via `/dev/stdout`.

UPDATE: I can also run the `quota-warning.sh` script manually from a shell inside the container without a problem. It drops a warning message into the users mailbox.

Comment: Are you using `chroot` anywhere?  `/dev/stdout` symlinks to `/proc/self/fd/1` on Linux machines, try using this file as an alternative without the symlink in-between.

Comment: I've already tried with `chroot=` in the `service quota-warning { ... }` section and it didn't help. Also `/proc/self/fd/1` doesn't make a difference. It must have to do with the way how dovecot spawns the quota warning script. Actually I couldn't find any information about what exactly `script` does in the  `executable = ...` line above. Maybe it could be tweaked somehow?

Comment: I'd propose to try `ls -l /dev /prod/self /prof/self/fd / > /some/location` (or pipe into lda if you don't fine the file again) to get an  understanding what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you do the following:

Change the user executing the quota-warning script to *root*:

`service quota-warning {
  executable = script /usr/local/bin/quota-warning.sh
  user = root
}`

Even when running the script as root (which is not ideal from a security perspective), it doesn't work, though.

So I appended the following options to the *dovecot-lda* command line:

`/usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d $USER -o "log_path=/proc/1/fd/2" -o "info_log_path=/proc/1/fd/1" -o "plugin/quota=maildir:User quota:noenforcing"`

When doing so, logging is redirected to the STDOUT and STDERR of the process with PID=1, which is the process whose output normally gets logged by docker.

I don't know why /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr are not available to the quota-warning script, even if it is run by *root*...

Did you find a better solution in the meantime?

Best regards,
Stefan

Comment: I ended up adding socklog as a lightweight syslog alternative to capture dovecots log messages. It's been a while so I'm not sure but I think it also logs the quota warnings. Can't test it right now.